# Rails client side validations -- disable submit until validations pass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Title is self-explanatory. I am using [client side validation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) in rails and it works wonderfully. However, I don't want the submit button on my form to be enabled until all the validations pass.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are callback functions:

```
ClientSideValidations.callbacks.form.pass(form, eventData)
ClientSideValidations.callbacks.form.fail(form, eventData)
```

You can disable the submit button by default and on `fail`. and enable it on `pass`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why these callbacks wouldn't be firing?

Comment: @davepaola those events will only fire when the form is submitted so they're not directly used for disabling/enabling a submit button.

I'm trying to do the same thing. I need a callback that runs every time the errors are updated. When the error count is zero I can enable the submit button.

Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody more recent comes along looking for an answer to this, Alexey's answer is pretty much correct. Currently, there are callbacks available on the elements that you could use.

https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#callbacks